# How to play 360 mp4 vids?

Tags: android, youtube, android-video-player, android-videoview, 360-virtual-reality

I'm fascinated by the 360 videos on YouTube as of recently. I'd like to develop a sample Android application that can play a 360 video and be able to pan/swipe with it along with being able to use accelerator/gyroscope.

Few questions:

1. What file format is 360 video? Where can I download sample 360 video?
2. Is it even possible to use Android library to play 360 video? If so, what player would I need to use to "play" 360 video?
3. How can I handle pan/swipe for a 360 video played by the native player?
4. Is it possible to play an existing YouTube 360 video using Android native Player? And at the same time be able to handle pan/swype/gyro?

Please provide a code sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

360 Videos are just videos recorded by a 360 camera. What separates them from a normal video is just the meta data.

Use panframe library for Android/iOS.
http://www.panframe.com

Comment: Visit the link and download the Panframe SDK for Android. The library supports navigation by touch and motion. And yes, it has samples. Run one of them and you will understand how it works. You can use either one of those to build your application. It's pretty straightforward. Ask if you get stuck. And please mark this answer as accepted if it was helpful :)

Comment: exist any free?